# Decode UTF-8 String Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to decode a string which is in UTF-8 format, into normal human readable string and tried may codes available on SO. But non of these worked.

My demo UTF-8 String is :-

```
let demoString: String = "à¤¯à¥ à¤ªà¤¹à¤²à¥ à¤ªà¤¹à¤²à¥ à¤à¤¾à¤¹à¤¤à¤¯à¥ à¤¬à¤¹à¤à¥ à¤¬à¤¹à¤à¥ à¤¹à¤¾à¤²à¤¤"
```

Is there is anyway to decode this UTF-8 String in swift. Any help would be appricated.

Comment: What do you mean by decode ? The string is the characters you see.

Comment: this is in utf-8 encode format, it is hindi sentence in normal format

Comment: Decoding it with NSUnicodeStringEncoding gives a result but it doesn't look like Hindi? I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the source of the string? This is UTF-8 decoded as if it was some variant of ISO-8859, but if it has been properly decoded in the first place it would show up correctly.

Comment: It is slightly broken, though, what looks like `à¥ ` (`e0 a5 20`) is of course not valid UTF-8.

Comment: Can't you just write the string? e.g. `let hello = "नमस्ते"`

Comment: Himanshu cross check your string it doesn't appears to be an NSUTF-8 encoded string. I have verified that it's not UTF-8 encoded at following online tool https://mothereff.in/utf-8

Comment: I agree, your string should be more in the format `let str = "\u{0906}\u{092A}"` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
let demoString: String = "à¤¯à¥ à¤ªà¤¹à¤²à¥ à¤ªà¤¹à¤²à¥ à¤à¤¾à¤¹à¤¤à¤¯à¥ à¤¬à¤¹à¤à¥ à¤¬à¤¹à¤à¥ à¤¹à¤¾à¤²à¤¤"
```

This defines a perfectly fine string containing some rather weird characters like "à", "¤" and so on. There is no decoding that can be done here. The first character is a "Latin Small Letter A With Grave", U+00E0 or C3A0 in UTF-8 format.

If you want a string with "Hindi" characters - I suppose you mean Devanagari, or Bengali, Gurmukhi, Gujarati etc. , type for example

```
let demoString: String = "ऄइउऋऌऍ"
```